# How do I insert dynamic text into Spring MVC error messages?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a Spring MVC application running in Tomcat, and it's all working well.

One thing I need to be able to do is customise an error message with text that I've got at runtime. I'm not especially familiar with either Spring or Java resource bundles. I've tried this in my `.properties` file:

```
exception=Something bad, m'kay? {0}
```

But that gets repeated verbatim in the `<form:errors>` output.

Two questions:

(1) How do I supply the runtime text to the `Errors` object in my controller, and
(2) How do I format the property text to include that runtime text.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `rejectValue(String field, String errorCode, Object[] errorArgs, String defaultMessage)` api in `Errors` to include your runtime text.

If we apply this api to your error message stated in your question
`errors.rejectValue(<your_command_field>, exception, new Object[]{<your_runtime_string>}, 
"Something bad, m'kay? fine")`

Comment: I'm still not clear on how my runtime text is merged into the canned resource text.

Comment: That API loads your message text into memory and replaces those place holders(like {0},{1}...) with your dynamic strings you passed as Object array in the same order and returns that string. i.e {0} will be replaced with Object[0] and {1} with Object{1}...

Comment: That's the bit that's not working. The message I get from <form:errors> is "Something bad, m'kay {0}". The "{0}" isn't replaced with my text.

Comment: it would be great if you can add your controller code about how you are adding errors...